# Trouble when passing a variable to an include template

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm stuck on my project. I have a link (`mailto:[...]`) on a div of class jumbotron, included by the page I'm working on for tests.
This link is  here for purpose of concertation with people involved in that project for them to give their comments.

So, in my controller, I save the request URI in the variable `from`:

```
/**
     * @Route("/sitemap", name="site_map")
     */
    public function sitemap(Request $requete): Response
    {
        $from = $requete->server->get('REQUEST_URI');
        return $this->render('public/sitemap.html.twig', [
            'from' => $from
        ]);
    }
```

Next, the sitemap template call the jumbotron and try to send the var "from":

```
{% block jumbo %}
    {% include "shared/_jumbo.html.twig"  with {
'jumbo':"Plan du site",
        'leadText':"",
'description':"",
'from': from,
'produitAjout':false}
        %}
{% endblock %}
```

At last, the jumbotron receive the variable "from" and it should appear on the mail client as the body of the mail :

```
    <a href="mailto:info@richardjuan.com?subject=StJoV4 - commentaire&body=Depuis l'adresse: {{ from }}">Laissez-moi vos commentaires...<a class="tooltip-link" date-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Vous pouvez joindre des copies d'écran pour illustrer votre propos, merci." aria-hidden="true">*</a>
        </a>
```

And I get the following error:

> Variable from does not exist.

Comment: We'll need more information. Can you explain what you mean with `the sitemap template call the jumbotron`? Also please post `/_jumbo.html.twig`

Comment: FYI: you don't need to pass known variables to an include with `with`, only if you wanted to rename the variables or if you use `with only`. Otherwise the variables known in the caller will also be known inside the included template

Comment: I mean 'include' the jumbotron template.

Comment: Well, please post the `_jumbo` template

Comment: The site map template knows the variable for I can see it with the inclusion {{ from }} in a div. I should I do to make the jumbotron template recognize the variable ?

Comment: Thank you everybody ! got it. I  used : {{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) }} directely in the link. That was so simple in fact, sorry for the time you lost.